# Impersonate in Tridion 2011 without using core service

Tags: tridion, impersonation

I'm trying to impersonate a user in a C# TBB. is it possible to know who initiated the publish action of a component in the TBB which is a part of the component template rendering with the component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in below article

> http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/05/publishing-from-template-code-using.html

Once you will get the **Current Publish transaction** you can use the properties **.Creator** to get the user.

To get the Current Publish Transaction you can refer

> http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/05/publishing-from-template-code-using.html

Comment: I was not able to get the current user by using : engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextItem.Session.User which I thought I would. The links provided had the solution. Many Thanks Ram.

Answer (score 6):

In your TBB you have access to the `engine.GetSession()`, which returns a `Session` object, containing the `User` information, I'm sure via that you can do in your code, what you are trying to achieve.

It would be interesting to know a little more about what you are trying to archive.

Comment: First of all thank you for the info John. It worked! I want to push a few items  to the publishing Q using the same user id which published the component which is getting rendered with the CT. So when some items are pushed to the Q automatically through code we know which user triggered it.

Comment: The engine.GetSession() contains a User for whom the Session was created. In your case (in templating), it's most likely the SYSTEM user. As I understand, Ram wants the user who 'initiated the publish'... and that's not SYSTEM.